# How to log an object in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script (I'm developing an add-on for Google Docs) and have trouble logging objects for debugging purposes.

For example, when I try to get the following information and log it

```js
let x = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
Logger.log(x);
```

the logger prints "Range". In other words, it seems to be printing the *type* of the object I'm trying to print, not a stringification of its keys and values (or whatever App Script objects are made of).

Instead, I would like to print that object's properties and the corresponding values.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(String,Object...)), it looks as though the Logger only takes strings. Therefore, I have tried stringifying the objects I'm trying to log, using `JSON.stringify`, e.g. `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(x));`, but then it just prints "{}". That seems wrong, given that I have made sure to select something in the document. The same happens for `getCursor()` even though I have my cursor positioned in the document.

Stringifying the objects before logging them seemed like a step in the right direction, but... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to go to the official documentation and see what `getSelection()` returns. Go the the object of this class and you will see all the available methods that this particular object (in your case `Range`) has. It is always a good practice not just in GAS but in every programming language to see what are the available methods for every instance/object you are dealing with.

Comment: This is also quite relevant to your question. See how the answer uses the result of `getSelection()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613263/11225291

Comment: Yes, well, checking what the available methods for the object I'm dealing with are is what I am trying to do by printing it. That's a lot more convenient than opening up Google's (terrible) documentation every time. Seeing how Apps Script seems very JavaScript-esque, I figured that should work... The `getCursor()` thing was just an example.

Comment: It is not a general solution, but for your specific sample you can log the strings contained in your object as following: `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection().getRangeElements().forEach(function(element){Logger.log(element.getElement().asText())});`

Answer (score 2):

Most if not all inbuilt object's properties are not enumerable(See [Enumerability and ownership of objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)).  You may be able to get most properties using a combination of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`,  `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`. You can get all their flags(`enumerable`,`configurable`, etc)  using  `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc
const getAllSelectionNames = () => {
  'use strict';
  const getObjNamesAndValues = x =>
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x).map(k => ({ [k]: x[k] }));
  const x = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (x) console.log(getObjNamesAndValues(x));
};
```