# onEdit function inserts more rows than coded for

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

My code is inside a Google Sheets file in my Google Drive:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lrxNzCmK4v2OOV3bmzCT_IGbJe30JjPP-7_JSEGWPjY/edit?usp=sharing

I've copied them here in case there are changes to the Google Sheets file or if you can't access it.  I want to insert 6 blank rows to part a few rows of data in the spreadsheet, but instead of 6 rows, the GAS interpreter inserts 12 rows instead.  Does anyone know why this happens and how to resolve it?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let c = e.range
    , cellrow = c.getRowIndex()
    , cellcol = c.getColumnIndex()
    , c2
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    ;
  /* code to part sea of words in spreadsheet */
  let cvalue = c.getValue();
  if (cvalue == "EVERY" || cvalue == "PARTY") {
    let [upper, left, right, lower] = checkNeighbours(c);
    let neighbours = [upper, left, right, lower]
    if (! allBlank(neighbours)) {
      // insert 6 rows and delete original word at original position
      c.getSheet().insertRowsAfter(c.getRowIndex(), 6);
      c.setValue("");
      // paste original word in cell 2 rows below original position
      cellrow += 2;
      c2 = sheet.getRange(cellrow, cellcol);
      c2.setValue(cvalue);
    }
  }
}
// return the (up to) 8 cells surrounding cell c
function checkNeighbours(c) {
  let nbUpperRow = c.offset(-1,-2,1,8)
      , nbLeft = c.offset(0,-2,1,2)
      , nbRight = c.offset(0,1,1,5)
      , nbLowerRow = c.offset(1,-2,3,8)
      ;
  return [nbUpperRow, nbLeft, nbRight, nbLowerRow];
}
// are all the cells given, blank?
function allBlank(rs) {
  for (var c of rs) {
    if (! c.isBlank()) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

[image: View of Spreadsheet before insert 6 rows]
[image: View of Spreadsheet after insert 6 rows]

Comment: You should consider learning how to use the event object more efficiently.  You're wasting a lot of time running functions to get information that's already in the event object.

Comment: Please share a sample test sheet with view permission.[Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383). I would also appreciate it if you could provide some information regarding your inputs. Based on my understanding when you input "EVERY" or "PARTY" and its neighbor cells are empty, you will insert 6 rows after your modified cell. What cell did you modified?

Comment: @RonM, Ok, I've just changed the view permissions of my file to "Anyone on the internet with the link can open".  When "EVERY" or "PARTY" is input, and the neighbour cells are not empty, 6 blank rows will be inserted, and the word "EVERY" or "PARTY" will be shifted 2 rows down into the space created by the inserted blank rows.

Comment: @Cooper, Thanks, I've just had a look at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events, but there don't seem to be much I can use there about event object that I haven't use..

Comment: `cellrow = c.getRowIndex() , cellcol = c.getColumnIndex()` these two function provide the same data as e.range.rowStart and e.range.columnStart and `c.getValue()` is the same at e.value and there's no overhead in the event object like there is in a function call.

Comment: @Cooper, Thanks, I've changed my code as you suggested, and the problem as stated by this post disappeared.  So, is the root cause of the erroneous result of GAS due to the GAS interpreter failing to handle functional overheads?  I'm asking this to get a better sense of GAS, because in the course of trying to resolve this problem, I've encountered a couple of solutions which seem to resolve this issue, but shed no light as to why it happens, and how it can be avoided in future..

Comment: Well if you are using the onEdit simple trigger then you should now that it must finish within 30 seconds.  And if you are going to have a lot of users editing the same spreadsheet then you need to route those triggers around the function as quickly as possible so it wont interfere with your desired functionality.  Remember a trigger is generated on every edit

Comment: @Cooper, I've actually created a list of all the properties associated with the Event object based on the code suggested at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345346/how-to-log-an-object-in-google-apps-script.  But there are almost 200 properties, and the list I've created is only an array of property names.. how will I be able to find out which ones are not methods, but purely properties like rowStart and columnStart?  I believe the reason for the long list, is that properties of the superclass Object is included alongside those specific to the Event object...

Comment: I use `function onEdit(e) {Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));}`  to get the event object properties.  Those are all the properties that give you information about the trigger event.     But yeah google apps script objects are pretty complex in some cases.  Personally, I've never looked into it that deeply.

Comment: I checked your code. It only adds 6 rows https://imgur.com/a/LXCnW1Z

Comment: @Cooper, I have a problem running your onEdit function, because when I create an event by typing in the spreadsheet, I can't see the execution log which Logger.log writes to, and when I check the script editor after typing in the spreadsheet, the execution log did not update...

Comment: @RonM, the problem only occurs when you type EVERY in the cell C2.  C3 is ok.  give it a try..

Comment: If you're telling me that you have two onEdit(e) functions then that's a problem because every function in a project has to have a unique name.  The one you added is probably not even being called.  Just add the JSON.stringify() to your current function.

Comment: @Cooper, I am only using one onEdit function.  i've tried on many occasions before.  onEdit just doesn't update the execution log in my script editor...

Comment: I can't see any Logger.log in your code so it's difficult to help you.